# count based embeddings with Gensim?

Tags: gensim, word-embedding

I would like to create a count-based word embedding based on one very large corpus using a fixed context window and bigram frequencies. I do not want to compare vectors between documents (or compare documents) but have a representation across on rather lengthy corpus.I am basically looking for a count-based co-occurrence model.

Is there any implementation of this within Gensim that I failed to discover? Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "frequency-based embeddings" that's different from regular word2vec (which is already highly-influenced by frequencies in its training process)? Is there a specific written-up approach you're referring to, & could link to for clarification?

Comment: Sorry, I meant count-based (edited the original post). Basically, I'm looking for a gensim approach to a HAL model.

Comment: Do you have a link to a canonical description of what you mean? Some Google queries using terms you've mentioned haven't definitively indicated a single distinct & useful thing you may mean mean, nor hinted what benefits this something-else might have over usual word2vec word embeddings. (As mentioned, those are already a product of word co-occurrence frequencies. Word2vec vectors are also not limited to comparing-between-documents, but rather are based on all usages across a "lengthy corpus" – exactly what you say you want.) What's driving this need to use some less-standard technique?

Comment: I am looking for an implementation of what is described in section 2.1.3. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/word-embeddings-count-word2veec/

Answer (score 0):

With the clarification that you mean the sort of vectors describe by [Section 2.1.3 of this article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/word-embeddings-count-word2veec/#:%7E:text=2.1.3%20co-occurrence%20matrix%20with%20a%20fixed%20context%20window):

There's no direct support in Gensim for that style of word-vector training.

It looks to me like an older, more expensive to calculate, and likely less-performant method than word2vec, so it's unclear why it'd be wanted for most projects. (Perhaps, it'd be of interest for an academic exploration of the history of word-embeddings?)

This method's extra overhead of managing the entire co-occurrence matrix, and its cost of a full PCA or SVD decomposition (especially in the case of larger corpora) was likely part of the motivation that led to the invention of word2vec's sparser training process, withc competitive results and more tweakable parameters for different uses.

That said, it seems to be somewhat similar to GLoVe, so if you needed to explore vectors created via a similar method, you could look into libraries that support GLoVe vector training. (And, dense vectors from other methods like GLoVe can usually be loaded into Gensim as `KeyedVectors` models, via common & simple shared vector-per-line storage formats.)

And, while expensive to calculate, the process as described is pretty simple, so (if you have the memory) you could reify the co-occurrence matrix yourself in a few lines of code, then apply Scikit-Learn's PCA or SVD, to implement it if really needed.

But using word2vec or FastText is likely to give better results costing less in compute resources.

Comment: Hi, thanks! As a follow up question: If I have a co-occurrence matrix of size vocabulary*vocabulary with -inf where co-occurence =0 how can I transform this into a 300D matrix using gensim?

Comment: The word2vec algorithm doesn't work off of co-occurrence matrices, but rather original texts. So there's not even a non-standard way to patch into the code to make that input work. The alternative GLoVe algorithm for word-vectors *does* internally use a co-occurrence matrix, so it *might* be possible to adapt your matrix for use with one of those implementations. (But I'm less familiar with those options, so can't recommend anything specific.)

Comment: Alternatively, if for some reason desperate to use only that wrong-format data in a Word2Vec/FastText-like algorithm, *maybe* using your matrix to generate a synthetic corpus would give a corpus that, while nonsense to human readers, would have the same sort of patterns, with regard to the same words, as sufficient to train a model that expects a corpus of real texts. (It vaguely seems to me it should, but it could introduce other problems, I'm not sure. And, I don't know any code to recommend such pseuocorpus generation, but it's likely not too complex & may exist in many places.)